# Echo forloop retrieved from phpmyadmin sql to div (PHP FILE)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have values/data stored in mysql and I want to echo them in a `div`. It's like displaying in a table. However, when I do that it only echos the first data and not all. Please advice.

```
     <?php
$sql = "SELECT budget_id, item, budget, paid, spent FROM budget WHERE title ='attireandaccssories' ORDER BY budget_id ";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultset);
        for ($i=0;$i<$rowcount;$i++){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset);
        $budget_id[$i]=$row['budget_id'];
        $item[$i]=$row['item'];
        $budget[$i]=$row['budget'];
        $paid[$i]=$row['paid'];
        $spent[$i]=$row['spent'];

       }
   ?>


   <?php
      for($i=0;$i<$rowcount;$i++){
        echo "$rowcount";
                 ?> 
  <div id="itemcomponent-attireandaccssories">
    <div id="itemcomponentjscontainer-attireandaccssories">
   <div id="itemcomponenttitle"><?php echo $item[$i]; ?></div>
   <div id="itemcomponentdelete" budget_id=<?php echo $budget_id[$i]; ?> ><i 
    class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true fa-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentspent"><?php echo $spent[$i]; ?></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentpaid"><?php echo $paid[$i]; ?></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentbudget" ><?php echo $budget[$i]; ?> </div>
    <div style="clear: both;" id="clearall" class="clearall"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the for() loop when fetching your results.

Comment: why are using loop twice?

Comment: first of check `$rowcount` no of rows, either getting or not, dont know where you initialize `$con`

Comment: Are you sure there are more than one row in the result?

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) you need to use while, this code works perfectly:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT budget_id, item, budget, paid, spent FROM budget WHERE title ='attireandaccssories' ORDER BY budget_id ";

$resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)){ ?>

  <div id="itemcomponent-attireandaccssories">
    <div id="itemcomponentjscontainer-attireandaccssories">
   <div id="itemcomponenttitle"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></div>
   <div id="itemcomponentdelete" budget_id="<?php echo $row['budget_id']; ?>" ><i 
    class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true fa-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentspent"><?php echo $row['spent']; ?></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentpaid"><?php echo $row['paid']; ?></div>
    <div id="itemcomponentbudget" ><?php echo $row['paid']; ?> </div>
    <div style="clear: both;" id="clearall" class="clearall"></div>
  </div>
  </div>

<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you @Williams. I tried while loop they only show me the first result . I am not sure why is that happening?

Comment: Hi william thank you. I realized my problem was with the javascript and not the code. Thank you very much. Both while and for loop works well.